# Add Swipe Gesture to display the next Item in the Detailed View

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uicollectionview

From the Collection View I have passed the details I want via segue to the Detailed View Controller.

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
   {
SportsCollectionViewCell *selectedCell = (SportsCollectionViewCell *)sender;
SportsBrowserViewController *targetVC = (SportsBrowserViewController *) [segue destinationViewController];
targetVC.targetURL  = selectedCell.targetURL;
targetVC.sdesc = selectedCell.description.text;
targetVC.stitle = selectedCell.title.text;
targetVC.simage = selectedCell.image.image;
targetVC.scat = selectedCell.category.text;
targetVC.sdate = selectedCell.date.text;


 }
```

I want to now add a swipe gesture to the destination view controller so that I can get to the next article without having to go back to the main page. I have added the following to set up the gesture.

```
     UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer;
recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeHandler:)];
[recognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}

-(IBAction)swipeHandler:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender{
NSLog(@"SWIPE");

}
```

However, I do not know how to move from here. Could someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I am trying to do here is play a sequence of images, by swiping.

```
-(IBAction)swipeHandler:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
{
    if(gesture.direction  == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)
    {
    if ((gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) ||
        (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)) {

        self.count--;
        if (self.count<0)
        {
            self.count=[yourArticlesArray count];
           // for round robin swiping.
        }

        CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
        animation.duration = 0.5;
        animation.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
        animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;

        [self loadArticleForIndex:self.count];

        [targetVC.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"imageTransition"];

    }
}

     else 
    {
        if ((gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) ||
            (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)) {

            self.count++;

            if (self.count>=[yourArticleArray count])
            {
                self.count=0;
            }

            CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
            animation.duration = 0.5;
            animation.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
            animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;

            [self loadArticleForIndex:self.count];

            [targetVC.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"imageTransition"];

        }
    }
  }
```

SO what I would suggest is take away my part and include the article loading part of yours, say like we have the count variable and guessing that you would have your articles in a array or something you could write a method like this,

```
  - (void)loadArticleForIndex:(int)index
  {
    //draw ur article or load your webview.

        if(index>0 && index <[yourArticleArray count])
        {  
        //instead of selectedCell take out articles from the array and feed it to your VC properties. 
        self.targetURL  = selectedCell.targetURL;
        self.sdesc = selectedCell.description.text;
        self.stitle = selectedCell.title.text;
        self.simage = selectedCell.image.image;
        self.scat = selectedCell.category.text;
        self.sdate = selectedCell.date.text;
        //do something after setting all stuff.
        }
  }
```

So during swipes calculate the count accurately and pass the count to the function like

```
   [self loadArticleForIndex:count];
```

Comment: If you want I could edit my code that may help u better, tell me if u want.

Comment: I am getting there but still a little confused. So please edit away so I see exactly where I should be going.

Comment: weirdest thing. I am getting a 'property count not found' error. Am I missing something?

Comment: Still stuck and I'm not sure how to move forward. I posted my update in another question because I did not know how to do this here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647620/add-swipe-gesture-to-display-the-next-item-in-the-detailed-view-revised?noredirect=1#comment27457841_18647620

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the view with details of next item, inside the swipe Gesture handler you can update the content of your view with next article content. You may use animation in same view to give a slide in effect while doing so.

Something like :

```
  self.targetURL  = newItem.targetURL;
  self.sdesc = newItem.description.text;
 self.stitle = newItem.title.text;
 self.simage = newItem.image.image;
self.scat = newItem.category.text;
self.sdate = newItem.date.text;
```

Comment: I'm revisiting this problem, could you expound on your suggestion please.

Comment: requirement is to move from source view to destination with swipe gesture resulting in slide animation with details updated. So i am suggesting to update the content and then create an animation to slide to give the same effect in gesture delegate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to go to the next article, and presumably, the one after that, etc., then you should pass the whole array (or whatever you're populating your table with) to the detail controller as well as the indexPath of the selected cell (so you know where in the array to get the first article).